# Fixing a Gateway ZX4800 (touchscreen)

Tags: graphics-card, bios, gateway, touchscreen

Normally, I could solve this issue by replacing a video card, bad RAM, CPU, etc, etc..  But in the case of the ZX4800, I do not know where to begin.

The computer/touchscreen partially boots/POSTs, but that is all.
What I mean is that the Gateway logo appears like normal, but that is all.

Normally, I would go to the BIOS, but it never gets there.  I can't even get to the Boot Menu.  All that it does is show the Gateway logo and go blank.  I have a feeling it has something to do with the video card, but I have no idea how to work on these touchscreens.

Does anyone have a clue where to begin?  Any tutorials that you know of? Any advice whatsoever would be great.

Comment: Nevermind, apparently just letting the thing sit unplugged for a week fixed it completely.

Comment: For those interested, I found an instruction manual for dis-assembly
http://www.scribd.com/doc/78450796/34/Disassembly-Process

Answer (score 1):

I found the [manual to the computer](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Gateway%20Computers/ZX4800/Manual/149033).  Hope it helps. Test the machine with a repair disc, if you can't boot it is the bios. Then that means you have to rest the bios clock by opening up your machine and taking of the battery for 2 minutes then you put it back, close the case and test again.